# How to reset <f:ajax> disabled attribute

Tags: jsf

given the following code:

```
 <h:inputText id="minRate" value="#{bakingController.minRate}">
    <f:convertNumber type="currency" pattern="#{msg.currencyPattern}" maxFractionDigits="0"/>                                                    
    <f:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{bankingController.listProviders()}" execute="minRate" render="minRate btn-submit" disabled="#{facesContext.validationFailed}"/>
 </h:inputText>
```

i would like to disable the ajax-listener if the validation is failed for the first keyup-event, e.g. user enters some non-digits. but when i clear the input field or enter a valid number then, it won't get reactivated, although the parent field is re-rendered. how can i solve that?

may you answers help.

Answer (score 0):

there was a thinking flaw -.-

i have to validate with javascript if the input matches the appropriate format. then the listener will only be called, if the javascript-function returns true. so the disabled attribute is not needed.

```
<h:inputText id="minRate" value="#{bakingController.minRate}" onkeyup="return $.isNumeric(this.value)">
    <f:convertNumber type="currency" pattern="#{msg.currencyPattern}" maxFractionDigits="0"/>                                                    
    <f:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{bankingController.listProviders()}"     
                          execute="minRate" render="minRate btn-submit"/>
</h:inputText>
```